# How to create a directory in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard

Everything is in the question. Here is my code :

```java
private void createDirectory(File currentDirectory) 
{
    File f = null;
      
    try {
        f = new File(currentDirectory.getCanonicalPath() + "/directory" + count);
    
        boolean success = f.mkdir();

        if (!success) {
            Toast.makeText(currentContext, f.getName() + " could not be created", 15).show();
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Toast.makeText(currentContext, f.getName() + " could not be created", 15).show();
    }

    count++;
}
```

I am writing a small file manager in Android and I would like to add the possibility to create a directory. There is no exception and the variable success always return false.
Can someone tell me what is wrong my code??

Thx for your advice !!

**[EDIT]**

BTW, When the phone is in Developpement mode,  does an application has a write access on the sdcard? I am programming on my phone (Acer liquid)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

By the way, not sure how you are getting the SDcard directory... but it must be this way:

```
File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

It's important, because some programmers use to think that the SDCard is always /sdcard, but it could change.

Comment: Yeah, i know. But this is the way i get it. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Just a heads up for people who tumble upon this thread, starting from API level 19 (KitKat), `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission is not required for using external storage directory.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to your manifest file to tell Android to ask the user for your application to be allowed to.

Answer (score 2):

First, please use the `File` constructor that takes a `File` for your directory and a `String` for your desired subdirectory.

Beyond that, most likely you are attempting to create a directory where you are not allowed, either because:

- `currentDirectory` does not exist, or
- `currentDirectory` points to a place on the on-board flash storage where you are not allowed to write, or
- `currentDirectory` points to a place on the external storage and you lack the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission

Answer (score 0):

instead of `boolean success = f.mkdir();` use

```
boolean success = f.mkdirs();
```

that solved my problem (i used the same reference code as you and had the same issue).