# Directory not created

Tags: android, file

I am trying to create a directory and code runs without raising an exception, but directory is not created (checked with Android File Transfer app on Mac). There's no entry in the logs. What is going wrong here?
Permissions are in place

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Here's the code:

```
File path = getFilesDir();

    File filenew = null;

    try {
        filenew= new File(path+"/equation");
        filenew.mkdirs();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: getFilesDir().getPath + "/equations"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a directory in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776426/how-to-create-a-directory-in-android)

Comment: try `File filenew=new File(getFilesDir(),"equation");) filenew.mkdirs()`

Comment: In this case I get
/data/data/com......equations/files/equation
in filenew
and no directory created on device

Comment: I rebooted device, and now directory are there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
String externalDirectory= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File folder= new File(externalDirectory + "/NewFolder");
folder.mkdir();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/MYFOLDER");
             if(!root.exists()){
                 root.mkdirs();
                }
```

Comment: Doesnt work. What is strange is that my variable filenew contains /storage/emulated/0/equation when I do
filenew=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"equation");
filenew.mkdirs();